# Call something with the variable of a for

Tags: java, android

Im trying to call some ImageButtons on a for using the variable i and I dont know how to do it. I tried to link with the name but It's impossible.

Can anyone help me please?

```
for(int i=0;i<main.img.size()-1;i++){
    img.get().ImageButton1.setImageBitmap(vectorBp.elementAt(i));
    img.get()."ImageButton"+i+"".setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: img is a String array and I need to put the image of the array on the ImageButton and make visible. The problem is that I need to do dinamically because there will be a lot of images.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `img` is of type `List`, so call `img.get(i)`.

But then learn about `Iterator` and so called "for each" syntax introduced in java 5:

```
for (SomeType elem : listOfTheSameType) {
    // do what you want with the elem
}
```

Comment: The problem is call to different ImageButtons, no to the position of the list.